# Does PowerShell discriminate against visible, hidden, and very hidden Excel Worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to check the worksheet name in a workbook.  However, this worksheet is a "very hidden" worksheet.  Does this cause PowerShell to miss these sheets or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheet visibility is just a property that controls how Excel shows the worksheet - it's still a regular worksheet.

In the following example, "Book1.xlsx" is a new workbook where Sheet3 has been renamed and set to very hidden:

```
PS C:\> (New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application).Workbooks.Open("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets |ft Name,Visible -AutoSize

Name        Visible
----        -------
Sheet1           -1
Sheet2           -1
superhidden       2
```

[image: Excel workbook with hidden sheet]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  This is exactly what I needed to know.